# How to make the buttons appear in two columns correctly

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm having a little visual problem. I have a series of product categories, which have subcategories.

I'm showing the category buttons, and clicking opens a panel with the subcategories corresponding to the category.

The problem is that the second category appears below, and not next to the first category as it happens with all others. I'm using Bootstrap

I leave the code of that section and an image of how it is displayed

```
<?php

$item = null;
$value = null;

$category = ProductController::ctrShowCategory($item, $value);                        

    foreach ($category as $key => $value) {

        echo '<div class="col-xs-6 btnCategory">

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                    <a>'.$value["category"].'</a>

                </button>

                <div class="infoSubCategory"';

                $item = "id_category";

                $value = $value["id"];

                $subcategory = ProductController::ctrShowSubCategory($item, $value);

                echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["route"].'" class="showAll"><strong>Show All</strong></a></center></li>';

                foreach ($subcategory as $key => $value) {

                        echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["route"].'">'.$value["subcategory"].'</a></center></li>';
                    }   

                                 echo '</div>

            </div>';

    }

?>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icoxa.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the rendered HTML with CSS so we don't have to try to put humpty dumpty back together?

Comment: Don't use a list, My first thought is to just float the `li` elements.  CSS `float:left`etc.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Try to make a sample, but if I do it by nesting many divs to show several buttons, without taking into account the foreach with the php variables, everything is displayed correctly. And the problem could not be seen

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I've tried but it's not the problem. If all this I do without taking into account the foreach and php variables, making a simple sample of several buttons, it works fine, but I do not understand why this does not work

Comment: without this `Can you post a sample of the rendered HTML` as suggested above, it's just a guessing game.  __Here is a hint__ though, where is your `<ul>` tag.  It's no where to be found in that PHP code.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I have solved it! As simple as putting all the foreach of the buttons that are generated inside a row. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! As simple as putting all the foreach of the buttons that are generated inside a row.

```
<?php

$item = null;
$value = null;

echo '<row>';

$category = ProductController::ctrShowCategory($item, $value);                        

    foreach ($category as $key => $value) {

        echo '<div class="col-xs-6 btnCategory">

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                    <a>'.$value["category"].'</a>

                </button>

                <div class="infoSubCategory"';

                $item = "id_category";

                $value = $value["id"];

                $subcategory = ProductController::ctrShowSubCategory($item, $value);

                echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["route"].'" class="showAll"><strong>Show All</strong></a></center></li>';

                foreach ($subcategory as $key => $value) {

                        echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["route"].'">'.$value["subcategory"].'</a></center></li>';
                    }   

                                 echo '</div>

            </div>';

    }

echo '</row>';

?>
```